# Model Selection on Coxme

Tags: model-selection, cox-model, rare-events

I am building a "time to event" model using the coxme package in R. I have a lot of mixed effects (15) that I want to input into a global model and find the best fit for - is there a model selection package like MuMln that can handle this type of model? If I try to run an ANOVA on the global model, it can't compute it (likely because there are simply too many variables).

Comment: Those who frequent this site are [highly skeptical of automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/28500). There is almost certainly a better way to address the scientific issues of your study. Please edit the question to provide more details about the data and what you are trying to learn from the data. For example: what is the nature of the event, what are the (fixed-effect) variables that you think might be influencing the time to event, what are the candidates for random effects in the model, and how many events you have?